# Facebook not working on windows 8.1 anymore

Tags: lumia-520, facebook

Since last wednesday (14.2.2018) neither me(Nokia Lumia 520) nor my friend(Nokia Lumia 530) cannot use Facebook anymore. Both phones are still on Windows 8.1, and didn't manually updated software).
What's the problem? Well, I cannot click on the icons on the top for new friends, messages and notifications, unless I hold my finger on it so long, that it offers me to open it in new tab.
After I open it in new tab, then I can read private messages, but cannot reply: the "send" button isn't working, unless I rapidly press it about 10-20 times while also pressing "enter" button on the keyboard.

Was there any kind of an update or something? Did facebook changes/updated it's own platform so it's not working on it anymore or something?
Anyone else got the same problem? (I guess I'm not the only one)

Comment: Are you using the Facebook app, or the website within the browser?

Comment: Website within the browser. I'd use the app, but there ain't any apps at all for WPs :)

Comment: Odd, there certainly *used to be* an app for Facebook

Comment: Okay, just downloaded an app, it's working great. The thing is, that it doesn't offer to send PMs, it just offers me FB Messenger. Ok, if I download it, same problem as before: can't start a conversation with anyone, messages cannot be send.

Comment: My lumia 520 has exactly the same problem as you describe. It started around the same date as well. I've tried using the UC Browser which does accept input on the blue notification bar but fails at loading a lot of sub pages on Facebook correctly. Also tried flashing my phone again, but that did not solve the problem. Looks like something on the mobile FB page is broken specifically for our Windows 8.1 phones.

Comment: @Rickv.Nooij: Yeah. I guess it's kinda "update" either of win8.1 or facebook.
I was thinking about flashing my phone too, but was my instinct telling me, that this won't solve the problem. As you've said you've done it, I'm sure now.
What about upgrading the phone up to win10? Is it possible for lumia 520?

Comment: Same issue on Lumia 1020. At the beginning they turned off Messenger and Skype on WP 8.1, then this. I think this is intentional update to force WP8.1 users to switch to newer phones or other Android/iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have wondered if it was an Internet Explorer specific issue, but so far I've not had any issues with other mobile websites I visit.

If the combination of IE11 and the Facebook page code are the problem, upgrading to W10M and Edge should likely solve it.

Unfortunately the Lumia 520 was excluded from the W10 upgrade. I'm currently scanning through the possibilities of getting around that.

If I succeed I'll let you know

Comment: Thanks for the info.
Is there any official statements or announcements about this "update" or what-so-ever happened?
Because I just see this event just another reason to cross over to the Android. Unfortunatelly.

Comment: In my quest for answers I've not come across anything that would explain the sudden change in behaviour yet. Some posters on isitdownrightnow.com appear to be having the same problems, though. But they haven't posted any specifics on what phones or platforms they're using.  

Installing W10m on a Lumia 520 appears to be possible, but it requires a registry hack to make it appear like a newer model phone and downloading the Windows Insider app to upgrade. Sounds a bit to tedious to me.

Comment: Yes looks like Lumia has issues. Can other browsers work instead of IE?

Comment: I've tried 1 or 2 but didn't.
But I've managed to use FB on winowsphone simmilar to what it was before.
To "open" messages, hold a finger on the icon, then open it in a new bookmark.
To send a private message, press send then enter on a keyboard. You gotta get feeling for that. Has to be ~0.5 seconds difference.

Comment: I've solved the problem by buying a Lumia 650 :\